# Kafka exactly-once semantics producer

Tags: apache-kafka

Does a Kafka producer with `enable.idempotence=true` and `acks=all` have exactly-once semantics?

Or, can it still produce two messages, and what possibly would need to happen for that to occur?

I'm considering this only from the perspective of Kafka producer, without any business logic around Kafka that could create all sorts of magic... Also, the semantics of Kafka consumers are not relevant in this context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't create 2 messages until the lifetime of the producer.
Producers are assigned with a Producer Id during initialization. That will be different in case producer restart. So producer life time is important.

Excerpt from Exactly once design [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Jqy_GjUGtdXJK94XGsEIK7CP1SnQGdp2eF0wSw9ra8/edit):

> To implement idempotent producer semantics, we introduce the concepts
> of a producer id, henceforth called the PID, and sequence numbers for
> Kafka messages. Every new producer will be assigned a unique PID
> during initialization. The PID assignment is completely transparent to
> users and is never exposed by clients.

On top of the configurations mentioned in your question, you need to set two more additional configurations to get idempotency; `retries> 1` and `max.inflight.requests.per.connection=1`

Comment: How does the lifetime affect this, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Is this correct that if the producer is restarted, and a new producer instance is created, the sequence number might reset. This could lead to a situation where messages that were in-flight (sent but not acknowledged) during the restart are resent by the new producer instance, potentially leading to duplicates...?